# How to split test and train data in a dataset based on number of targets in each category

Tags: python, pytorch

I have an `imageFolder` in PyTorch which holds my categorized data images. Each folder is the name of the category and in the folder are images of that category.

I've loaded data and split train and test data via a sampler with random `train_test_split`. But the problem is my data distribution isn't good and some classes have lots of images and some classes have fewer.

So for solving this problem I want to choose 20% of each class as my test data and the rest would be the train data

```
ds = ImageFolder(filePath, transform=transform)
batch_size = 64
validation_split = 0.2

indices = list(range(len(ds))) # indices of the dataset

# TODO: fix spliting
train_indices,test_indices = train_test_split(indices,test_size=0.2) 

# Creating PT data samplers and loaders:
train_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(train_indices)
test_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(test_indices)

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(ds, batch_size=batch_size, sampler=train_sampler, num_workers=16)
test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(ds, batch_size=batch_size, sampler=test_sampler, num_workers=16)
```

Any idea of how I should fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `stratify` argument in `train_test_split` according to the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html). If your label indices is an array-like called `y`, do:

```py
train_indices,test_indices = train_test_split(indices, test_size=0.2, stratify=y)
```

Comment: I used it and it gets an error like this: 
`targets = np.array(ds.classes)

train_indices,test_indices = train_test_split(indices,test_size=0.2,stratify=targets) `

Comment: `Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [15340, 52]`

Comment: or should I use `class_to_idx` or `targets` ?

Comment: I used `dataset.tags` for `y`

Comment: Hmm, when you see that error it typically means length of X and y don't match up, might want to double check to be sure. Here's a related question that might be helpful: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/20199/train-test-split-error-found-input-variables-with-inconsistent-numbers-of-sam

Answer (score 1):

Try using [StratifiedKFold](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html) or [StratifiedShuffleSplit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html#sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit).

According to the docs:

> This cross-validation object is a variation of KFold that returns stratified folds. The folds are made by preserving the percentage of samples for each class.

In your case you can try:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit
sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=5, test_size=0.5, random_state=0)
for train_index, test_index in sss.split(ds):
    train = torch.utils.data.Subset(dataset, train_index)
    test = torch.utils.data.Subset(dataset, test_index)
    trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=0, pin_memory=False)
    testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=0, pin_memory=False)
```

Comment: So I have to use `lableEncoding` before using it?

Comment: Thanks. So I can't use my `SubsetRandomSampler ` here?

Comment: StratifiedKFold is usually a technique to find the best training data for your use case, so you would train multiple models with different training data, to avoid that put a `break` at the end of the for loop